# Java Script Input format validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to validate the below format of one of the input fields

```
1111-111-111 //4digits- 3digits- 3digits
```

I tried the below method but its not working. Any idea of what am I misisng?

```
function(value) {
    var patt = "/^\d{4}-d{3}-d{3}$/";
    var res = value.match(patt);
    if (!res) {
        return {
            status: 2,
            message: 'Input should be formatted as 0000-000-000'
        };
    } else {
        return {
            status: 0
        };
    }
}
```

Also, given a string, I wanted to enforce characters at certain indices are empty. 
like for eg: 23 total characters, where 2nd, 9th, 11th and 13-21 are space characters.
I am new to Javascript regex, how do we enforce these?

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is wrong. Fix it:

```
/^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/
```

Your second part and third part are "d" characters, not numbers.
And remove the `"` characters when declare a regex.

```
var patt = /^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/;
```

Comment: But then the `res` is coming as null. why is it so?

Comment: @Programmerzzz, try to use `patt.test(value)`

Comment: remove the `"` character when define a regex

Answer (score 2):

If we only wish to pass 4-3-3 digits, we could simply do that using:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2Mmvk/2/)

or:

```
^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5fnwYK/1/)

If we wish to also capture the phone number, we would be adding a capturing group:

```
^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})$
```

```js
const regex = /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/gm;
const str = `1111-111-111
1111-111-1111
8888-888-888`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first pattern does not work like intended because to match a digit you have to escape the d like `\d` or else `d{3}` would match 3 times a `d` character and the pattern should not be between double quotes but between `/`...`/`

```js
let test = function(value) {
  var patt = /^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/;
  var res = value.match(patt);
  if (!res) {
    return {
      status: 2,
      message: 'Input should be formatted as 0000-000-000'
    };
  } else {
    return {
      status: 0
    };
  }
};

console.log(test("1111-111-111"));
```

For matching spaces at the places 2nd, 9th, 11th and 13-21 in the string you could use [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and `\S` to match a non whitespace character:

```
^\S \S{6} \S \S {11}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m7eAWp/1)

If you want to match by index based on a zero index, the pattern would look like:

```
^\S\S \S{6} \S \S {10}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YftKvp/1)